# OpenJDK 17 can't use ShenandoahGC

Tags: java, parameters, garbage-collection, startup, java-17

I have downloaded the binaries of jdk17 from [OpenJDK's Homepage](https://jdk.java.net/archive/), put the extracted directory to `/usr/lib/jvm/` where the other JDKs are and created a link with `ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.2/bin/java /usr/bin/java17`.

The development team from OpenJDK are stating that Shenandoah is available in all stable releases from Java 17.

But if I run `java17 -XX:+UseShenandoahGC`, than the following appears:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Option -XX:+UseShenandoahGC not supported
```

How do I get ShenandoahGC running?

Specs:

- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- JDK: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: As that link says _"**WARNING**: These older versions of the JDK are provided to help developers debug issues in older systems. They are not updated with the latest security patches and are not recommended for use in production."_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think you mix up jdk.java.net with OracleJDK which are not directly connected. jdk.java.net provides "The official Reference Implementation for Java". (which as you correctly stated are not meant for productive use)

Comment: @asbachb I'm not mixing that up. As far as I'm aware, the builds on jdk.java.net are prepared by Oracle, likely using the build profile Oracle uses itself (given the fact the OP can't enable Shenandoah, and Oracle doesn't provide Shenandoah either).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ahh that is something i didn't knew, that the releases on the site i posted are from oracle directly. I will try it with vendor releases and write back if it has functioning. ^^

Comment: You're right: "Oracle: Does not ship Shenandoah in any release, both OpenJDK builds and proprietary builds" https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/shenandoah/Main

There's also a list of vendors shipping ShenandoahGC.

Comment: It works now, I am using Adoptium Temurin 17.0.4+8. Thanks for your help ^^